# Facebook sdk not compiling when adding dependency to Dagger 2

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, dagger-2

I had dagger included in build.gradle (app) as follows:

`{compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'}`

Now I am trying to upgrade my project to Dagger 2.0 and create unit test with Mockito and Espresso, my new dependency consists of:

`compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`

I have Facebook SDK included in the project included in the project and I am getting error as `error: cannot find symbol class R`

I also have added as repository `maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }`

I would appreciate any help understanding what is going on here and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Project build.gradle as a dependency{}

**classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'**

and add this to the module build.gradle

**apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'**

Answer (score 0):

View https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/2.1-SNAPSHOT/

there is no 2.0-SNAPSHOT version. Just change your `2.0-SNAPSHOT` to `2.1-SNAPSHOT`. It helps to me in same case.